# JMeter error while running from Jenkins "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "timeStamp"

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter

I am getting below error when running JMeter script via Jenkins.Not able to figure out what is causing error.

```
Performance: Failed to parse file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\JMeter Test\builds\12\performance-reports\JMeter\test.jtl': For input string: "timeStamp"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "timeStamp"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.JMeterCsvParser.getSample(JMeterCsvParser.java:153)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.JMeterCsvParser.parse(JMeterCsvParser.java:124)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.JMeterParser.parseCsv(JMeterParser.java:189)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.JMeterParser.parse(JMeterParser.java:48)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:56)
    at hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.perform(PerformancePublisher.java:347)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Below is the content of test.jtl file

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime
1468432148291,2027,178 /BOT/,Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect,Clock-in / Clock-out Tests 1-1,text,false,,2204,7,7,0,0
1468432148608,2020,178 /BOT/,Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect,Clock-in / Clock-out Tests 1-2,text,false,,2204,8,8,0,0
1468432148941,2024,178 /BOT/,Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect,Clock-in / Clock-out Tests 1-3,text,false,,2204,9,9,0,0
1468432149255,1993,178 /BOT/,Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect,Clock-in / Clock-out Tests 1-4,text,false,,2204,9,9,0,0
```

Comment: Not super familiar with jenkins/jmeter, but I would suggest removing the first line (header) from the jtl file.

Comment: Thanks @lucasvw . You were right about the header row creating problem. I changed the output format for text.jtl from csv to xml and now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article it might be due to formats mismatch, i.e. [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) expects XML and gets CSV.

> For your first couple of runs, I recommend **“telling” JMeter to store its results in an XML format** using one of these approaches:
>
> - Add the ``jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml line to the ***user.properties*** file (this is located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation
> - Pass the property via the -J command-line argument, such as: `C:\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\jmeter\extras\Test.jmx -l Test.jtl`
>
> You can also use CSV files with the Performance Plugin. However, this requires extra  configuration whereas XML files work fine out of the box.